# Is it possible to move a servo without knowing it's current position?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

My Servo has already been built into my project, and I can't remove it without damaging many other things. During the process of inserting it, it was turned by hand. So I don't know at what position it is in. It turns a potentiometer that doesn't rotate fully. So I'm worried that if I just set a degree it could turn too far and damage the potentiometer or the servo.

What should I do to find the current position? Is it even possible?

Comment: Your final question is quite different from the title one. Yes, you can command an RC hobby servo without knowing its position, but no, you cannot move it **relative to the current position** if you do not know the PWM width that put it at that position, or where that position is within its range of movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A normal servo is an absolute positioning device. [The position of the servo is directly proportional to the length in time of the sync pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control#Pulse_duration).  This means if you tell the servo to be in a given position, it will seek that position with out regard to the initial position.  It will simply figure out which way to go on it's own and stop when it gets there.

I should add, that in all likely hood, when you manually moved the servo you moved the positioning potentiometer inside the servo.  So it is expected that if the servo is told to go to a particular angle, it will still go to the same angle as it did before you manually moved it.

Comment: tahnks, that really helped me :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Servo can rotate to a particular angle irrespective of previous position.

But you may face an issue here if you rotated the shaft manually by hand (when servo is not powered), and if you reassembled the shaft to the servo in a different orientation. Actually it is really hard to re assemble a removed shaft to the same angle position.